# Se puede poner instrucciónes dentro de Entry en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Se puede poner texto inicial de color gris dentro de un widget Entry en Tkinter para ayudar al usuario que tipos de datos introducir?

Por ejemplo.

Introducir el número 200 o el número 400

Y que cuando ponga el cursor en el cuadro de texto se borre y pueda escribir él las opciones.

Si hay una manera mas facil de decidir por dos opciones tambien lo agradecería que me lo explicaséis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En cuanto a la primera duda, que yo sepa, no hay nada que haga esto como tal en `Tkinter`. No obstante, se puede simular con una función (evento) asociada a sus correspondientes señales (foco en el Entry, ratón posicionado encima, etc):

Por otro lado hay varias formas de hacer que el usuario elija entre dos opciones (checkbuttons, listbox, combobox, menu, etc).

En el siguiente código tienes una posible forma de implementar lo que quieres usando el `Entry` y otra forma usando un `OptionMenu`:

```
from Tkinter import *



root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600+700+300")


#Ejemplo usando un Entry y señales-evento
def default(event):
    textoActual = caja.get()
    if textoActual == "Introducir el número 200 o el número 400":
        caja.delete(0, END)
        caja.config(fg = 'black')
    elif textoActual == "":
        caja.insert(0,"Introducir el número 200 o el número 400")
        caja.config(fg = 'grey')

caja = Entry(root)
caja.place(width=225, x=250,y=30)
caja.config(fg = 'grey')
caja.insert(0, 'Introducir el número 200 o el número 400')
caja.bind("<FocusIn>", default)
caja.bind("<FocusOut>", default)


#Ejemplo usando un OptionMenu
variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set("200")
menu = OptionMenu(root, variable, "200", "400")
menu.place(x=380,y=75)
etiqueta = Label(root, text="Seleccione un número:")
etiqueta.place(x=250,y=80)


root.mainloop()
```

Por otro lado, si usas de esta forma el `Entry` tienes que validar la entrada por si el usuario ingresa algo distinto de 200 o 400.

P.D: El código es para `Python 2.x`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el metodo set:

```
variable = StringVar
variable.set("ingresar dato")
```

Cuando se ejecute tu programa, en la entrada aparece la cadena ingresar dato, para darle colores y otras funciones debe haber probablemente, busca en la guia de *tkinter*.